# WCF certificates not being set on custom credentials

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, credentials, certificate

I have a custom implementation of ClientCredentials in WCF. Two of the base properties of ClientCredentials are the ClientCertificate and ServiceCertificate, as seen [here (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.clientcredentials_properties.aspx).

In my configuration, I have my custom ClientCredentials set, and both certificates defined:

```
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="MyCustomEndpointBehavior">
                <clientCredentials type="MyApp.Security.CentralAuthClientCredentials, MyApp">
                    <clientCertificate findValue="localhost" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" storeLocation="CurrentUser" storeName="My" />
                    <serviceCertificate>
                        <defaultCertificate findValue="localhost" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" storeLocation="CurrentUser" storeName="My" />
                        <authentication certificateValidationMode="None" revocationMode="NoCheck" />
                    </serviceCertificate>
                </clientCredentials>
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
```

This configuration was *completely 100%* working with UserName authentication. It used the certs to encrypt the username and password for the Message. Then I changed to my custom ClientCredentials.

At runtime, here are the properties that are set on my CentralAuthClientCredentials:

```
this.ClientCertificate = System.ServiceModel.Security.X509CertificateInitiatorClientCredential
this.ClientCertificate.Certificate = null
this.ServiceCertificate = System.ServiceModel.Security.X509CertificateRecipientClientCredential
this.ServiceCertificate.DefaultCertificate = null
```

So, why are the client and service default certificate that are defined in configuration *not* set on the actual instantiated object? It looks as if WCF ignored the XML tags completely!

Is there some code I can use, maybe in the constructor of the credentials, to get those certificates from the configuration manually?

Thanks for any help!

---

**Update**

I'm an idiot. I figured it out. WCF was actually creating my instance correctly with the certificates set, but in my wcf client, I had the following remove/add series, that I *think* I copied from the MSDN example:

```
this.ChannelFactory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Remove<ClientCredentials>();
this.ChannelFactory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new CentralAuthClientCredentials());
return base.Channel.MyServiceMethod();
```

To remove the old credentials and add my own custom ones.  However this was making a new instance that didnt have the certificates set! oops!

Comment: Can you show the binding that being used?

Comment: Could you post your solution to the answer and accept it so it doesn't show up in the unanswered questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So that I can mark this as answered, I'm adding my own solution, which was to remove this code from the client that makes a new credential:

```
this.ChannelFactory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Remove<ClientCredentials>();
this.ChannelFactory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new CentralAuthClientCredentials());
```

and use the one already set by WCF, instead of calling Remove() on it.